# Search-domain appending or prepending with Ubuntu 18 on WSL not working

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dhcp

this is driving me crazy, I am using WSL to run Ubuntu and I trying to add a domain to the domain search list that I am receiving via DHCP and it is not working
The funny thing is that I added that to the Win10 machine I am using and the host is fine
I tried to add this to /etc/dhcp/dhcpclient.conf

> prepend domain-search "lab.mydomain.com";

and I restarted the WSL service...it did not work
Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

For whoever is interested..this is a horrible bug
Microsoft says at the top of the resolv.conf file that if you remove a comment line there the resolv.conf will not be automatically updated anymore
Well that does not happen .... it lasts as long as your session. If you close the bash session next time when you start it resolv.conf is back to the initial state